# Python and MySQL Insert query

Tags: python, mysql

I have a question regarding insert query and python mysql connection. I guess that I need to commit after every insert query made

Is there a different way to do that? I mean a fast way like one in php.

Second this also is same for update query I guess ?

Another problem here is that once you commit your query connection is closed, assume that I have a different insert queries and every time i prepare it I need to insert it to the table. How can I achieve that with python. I am using  MySQLdb Library

Thanks for your answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to commit after each insert. You can perform many operations and commit on completion.

The [executemany](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0249/#id18) method of the DBAPI allows you to perform many inserts/updates in a single roundtrip

There is no link between committing a transaction and disconnecting from the database. See the [Connection objects methods](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0249/#connection-objects) for the details of the [commit](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0249/#commit) and [close](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0249/#Connection.close) methods